# Polymer's paper-dropdown-menu selected item font color

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, polymer, paper-elements

Using Polymer v1.0

I can't find the proper css to add to change the color of the selected value text.

[image]

When I inspect the element, I can change the color value for:
.paper-input-container-0 .input-content.paper-input-container label, .paper-input-container-0 .input-content.paper-input-container .paper-input-label

to white, and the text changes. But if I add that to my CSS, nothing changes.

Comment: Is your css getting applied after the frameworks stylesheet? are you using that exact same selector?

Comment: Yes and yes to those questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom styles like this:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    :host{
      --primary-text-color: blue;
      --paper-input-container-label: {
          color:orange;
      }
    }
</style>
```

default custom style is: --primary-text-color

Example:
http://jsbin.com/fuzuri/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work without an error and warnings. The CSS warnings are that it is invalid. I can't see the results of the jsbin showing a drop down.  The error is "DOM Exception 12: An invalid or illegal string was specified."